# Launch interactive session via script bridge

Tags: lldb

I am trying to launch an interactive debugging session from a python script via the SWIG-generated `lldb` module. The program to debug is nothing but an empty `main` function. Here is my current attempt:

```
import lldb
import sys
import os

debugger = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()
debugger.SetAsync(False)
target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch("a.out", "")

# The breakpoint itself works fine:    
fileSpec = lldb.SBFileSpecList()
mainBp = target.BreakpointCreateByName("main", 4, fileSpec, fileSpec)
mainBp.SetAutoContinue(False)

# Use the current terminal for IO    
stdout = os.ttyname(sys.stdout.fileno())
stdin = os.ttyname(sys.stdin.fileno())
stderr = os.ttyname(sys.stderr.fileno())

flag = lldb.eLaunchFlagNone

target.Launch(target.GetDebugger().GetListener(), [], [], stdin, stdout,
    stderr, os.getcwd(), flag, False, lldb.SBError())
```

It seems to me that whatever `flag` I pass to `target.Launch` (I tried amongst [those flags](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/blob/master/include/lldb/lldb-enumerations.h#L101)), there is no way of switching to an interactive editline session. I do understand that the primary purpose of the python bindings is non-interactive scripting, but I am nevertheless curious whether this scenario could be made possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method on SBDebugger to do this (RunCommandInterpreter).  That's how Xcode & similar make lldb console windows.  But so far it's only been used from C and there's something wrong with the C++ -> Python bindings for this function such that when you try to call it from Python you get a weird error about the 5th argument being of the wrong type.  The argument is an `int&` and that gives SWIG (the interface generator) errors at runtime.

Of course, you could just start reading from STDIN after launch and every time you get a complete line pass it to "SBCommandInterpreter::HandleCommand".  But getting RunCommandInterpreter working is the preferable solution.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight!! I'll try getting `RunCommandInterpreter` to work, that seems much better than the workaround.